# backbone view listenTo model object

Tags: backbone.js, rendering, render, backbone-views, backbone-model

I've a navigation view which is rendering again if the session status has changed. I want to have the same if the object `user` changes in the session model. But the line has no effect as the `user` object is not a attribute defined in the default section. Is there a way to listen or bind the render method of the NavView to the changes of the user object of the session model?

```
window.NavView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template : _.template($('#tpl-nav').html()),

    initialize : function() {
        window.session.on("change:logged_in", this.render, this);
        // this one is not working      
        window.session.on("change:user", this.render, this);
    },
);

window.SessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {
        logged_in : false,
        user_id : ''
    },

    initialize : function() {
        this.user = new User({ });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code `SessionModel.initialize` :

```
var self = this;
this.user = new User({ });
this.user.bind('change', function() { self.trigger('change:user'); });
```